# Gradle task --help printed to console instead of my application execution

Tags: java, spring, gradle, intellij-idea

This is my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.11.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example.ProjectJar'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
jar {
    from {
        (configurations.runtime).collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
    manifest {
        attributes("Main-Class": "com.example.ProjectJar.ProjectJar.FileSend" )
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    compile 'io.minio:minio:6.0.11'
}
```

But instead of execution of my main class that does have a main function, I get the following output:

> > Task :help
>
> Welcome to Gradle 5.6.4.
>
> To run a build, run gradle  ...
>
> To see a list of available tasks, run gradle tasks
>
> To see a list of command-line options, run gradle --help
>
> To see more detail about a task, run gradle help --task
>
> For troubleshooting, visit https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 43ms

What should I do to have my main class execute instead of this?

Comment: What is it that you are executing on the command line?

Comment: I simply ran my project. Executed nothing on the command line.

Comment: You ran what? You ran gradle not your project.

Comment: You have not specified what gradle command you run also you did not mention what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Try these :

```
gradle clean build
```

This command creates the spring-boot jar file to the build/libs directory or the target directory.
we can start our application by running the following command at the command prompt:

```
java -jar spring-boot-web-application.jar
```

Another way

```
./gradlew bootJar
```

This command creates the spring-boot jar file

To run the application is by executing the following Gradle command:

```
./gradlew bootRun
```